# How to maintain LDAP to login my own html?

Tags: django, ldap

Here is the current situation: I created a login.html page where I enter my username and password in a form. In my views.py I get the POST data and use the username and password to authenticate against my LDAP server (mechanism works). If the username/password is wrong, I am redirected back to the login page with an error message. Otherwise, I am redirected to a landing page where I will have a message like: "Hello Lastname, Firstname". 
I modify setting.py like this：

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS=(
    "django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend",
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
)

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://126.1.100.1:1234'

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = 'cn=ooxx,ou=example,dc=example,dc=com'

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "123456"

AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=example,dc=example,dc=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)")
```

When i run python manage.py shell

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
>>> user = authenticate(username="alex", password="123456")
```

i got this error information

```
search_s('ou=example,dc=example,dc=com', 2, '(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)') returned 1 objects: cn=alex,ou=user,ou=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
Exception while authenticating alex
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_auth_ldap/backend.py", line 320, in authenticate
    self._get_or_create_user()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_auth_ldap/backend.py", line 519, in _get_or_create_user
self._user, created = self.backend.get_or_create_user(username, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_auth_ldap/backend.py", line 209, in get_or_create_user
return model.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 146, in get_or_create
return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 484, in get_or_create
return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 398, in get
num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 106, in __len__
self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 317, in iterator
for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 775, in results_iter
for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 836, in execute_sql
sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 74, in as_sql
out_cols = self.get_columns(with_col_aliases)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 212, in get_columns
col_aliases)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 299, in get_default_columns
r = '%s.%s' % (qn(alias), qn2(field.column))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 52, in quote_name_unless_alias
r = self.connection.ops.quote_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 15, in complain
raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 60, in authenticate
user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_auth_ldap/backend.py", line 144, in authenticate
    user = ldap_user.authenticate(password)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_auth_ldap/backend.py", line 320, in authenticate
    self._get_or_create_user()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_auth_ldap/backend.py", line 519, in _get_or_create_user
    self._user, created = self.backend.get_or_create_user(username, self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_auth_ldap/backend.py", line 209, in get_or_create_user
    return model.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 146, in get_or_create
    return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 484, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 398, in get
    num = len(clone)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 106, in **len**
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 317, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 775, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 836, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 74, in as_sql
    out_cols = self.get_columns(with_col_aliases)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 212, in get_columns
    col_aliases)
       File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 299, in get_default_columns
    r = '%s.%s' % (qn(alias), qn2(field.column))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 52, in quote_name_unless_alias
    r = self.connection.ops.quote_name(name)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 15, in complain
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
    ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.